# Excel Dynamic Sorting using Formulas

Tags: excel, sorting, dynamic

I want to sort the table below by "Rank" AND if the value in "Rank" is greater than 20.

[image]

Expected output:

[image]

I found many useful articles but none helped me achieve the expected output.

useful article 1: http://excelbyjoe.com/using-excel-functions-to-dynamically-sort-data/

useful article 2: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2549-excel-find-first-last-value-greater-than.html

useful article 3: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1050-excel-find-closest-value.html

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data starts from `Cell A2` to `Column D`. Enter the following formula in the `Cell F2`

```
=SMALL(IF($A$2:$A$9>=20,$A$2:$A$9),ROW()-1)
```

This is an array formula so commit it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Now, in `Cell G2` enter the following formula

```
=VLOOKUP(F2,$A$2:$D$9,2,FALSE)
```

Then in `Cell H2` enter

```
=VLOOKUP(F2,$A$2:$D$9,3,FALSE)
```

and finally in `Cell I2` enter the following formula

```
=VLOOKUP(F2,$A$2:$D$9,4,FALSE)
```

Drag/Copy down all formula as required and change range as needed. See image for reference.

[image]

If you want records with RANK greater than 20 just remove the `=` sign from first formula.